# Как переносить название классов HTML в CSS?

Tags: html, css

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы мне не приходилось каждый раз копировать название классов `HTML`, чтобы вставить в `CSS`, для прописывания им стилей!
Как упростить эту задачу? Как сделать так чтобы я мог сразу много названий классов `HTML` переносить в `CSS`?

Comment: а ты сам подумай... Либо пиши программу, которая это будет делать, либо будь как все и просто переноси...

Comment: Это как это??? Что?)))

Comment: В брекетс эта опция есть

Answer (score 2):

Для этого можно использовать специальный плагин Tag.
Если что,это метод его установки в Sublime Text 3.
1.Скачиваем сам плагин : http://fls.guru/files/Tag.zip
2.Скачаный архив нужно распаковать в следующую папку: C:\users\Твоё имя пользователя\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packeges
2.a) Важно!!Проверяем, чтобы в папке Tag находились именно файлы, а не еще одна папка Tag. В противном случае вытягиваем папку Tag с файлами непосредственно в папку Packeges. Лишнюю (пустую) удаляем.
3.И биндим клавиши для удобной работы:
Preferences->Key bindings

[
{
"keys": ["ctrl+`"], "command": "tag_classes"
}
]

И если вам потребуется перенести классы элементов из html документа в CSS,то выделяете всё конструкцию,а не только класс, переходите в CSS документ и нажимаете Ctrl+v

Comment: а если нет папки sublime text 3 в том месте где вы указали? C:\users\Твоё имя пользователя\AppData\Roaming\- на этом месте заканчивается этот путь у меня!
Сам sublime text 3 я устанавливал несколько раз и все равно ничего не меняется!

Answer (score 1):

Если нет папки Sublime text 3, то распаковывать нужно в папке Packages/Tag.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/817058)

Answer (score 0):

В Sublime Text, указанный плагин Tag можно установить через Package Controll

1. в Add Repository добавляем репозиторий:
   https://github.com/titoBouzout/Tag
2. в Install Package ищем по слову tag
3. в Preferences->Key bindings добавляем:
   { "keys": ["ctrl+`"], "command": "tag_classes" }

Другие его функции доступны в меню Edit>Tag